# I have a local repository in spring boot and I want to access it through kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot

I have a local spring boot repository with this annotation in the pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repositorio.local</id>
            <name>Meu repositorio Local</name>
            <url>file:../maven-repositorio</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

So I use it to access other projects. my idea is to put the microservices in kubeenetes, this is how I call it in other projects:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do I make Kubernetes find this new repository?

Who can help me I'm grateful

Comment: The local .m2 is supposed to be where Maven finds dependencies.  Kubernetes is about deployment.  The package should be built by the time it reaches Kubernetes.  No need to be accessing Maven or repos after it arrives.  This is not how Maven and Kubernetes are supposed to work.

Comment: If I compile the local repository: <url>file:../maven-repository</url> and put it as a container, will it work? or do i need to create a volume? Thanks!

Comment: No, that's not how you should be using Maven.  Use Maven to create an executable Spring Boot JAR, put that in a Docker container with a JVM 17 or higher, and deploy that on Kubernetes.